# É possível pesquisar por comentários que eu fiz?

Tags: suporte, comentários

Eu sei que tem um site aqui no SO que você pode executar uma consulta SQL.

Tem como, por meio dessa página, fazer uma consulta dos comentários que eu fiz no SOpt ?

Comment: Obrigado. Eu imaginava que já tivesse uma pergunta assim, procurei, mas não encontrei. Pode fechar.